# How to create a data class for RestCountries json response. Android Retrofit

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit

First of all I'm building a small android app, basically when i click on the europe button for example, it will fetch data from https://restcountries.com/v3.1/region/europe. the problem is when i click on the button the recycler view is empty( it should display list of european countries). i added some logs and it shows that data is being fetched but recycler view adapter receives 0 Countries, so maybe main problem is the Data class.

Here's an example response: https://restcountries.com/v3.1/name/germany

Will this data class work for this type of response?

data class Country(
@SerializedName("name")
val name: Name,
@SerializedName("currencies")
val currencies: Currencies,
val capital: List,
val area: Double,
val flag: String
// Add other properties as needed to match your JSON structure
)

data class Name(
@SerializedName("common")
val common: String,
@SerializedName("nativeName")
val nativeName: Map<String, OfficialCommon>,
@SerializedName("official")
val official: String
)

data class OfficialCommon(
val official: String,
val common: String
)

data class Currencies(
@SerializedName("name")
val name: String,
@SerializedName("symbol")
val symbol: String
)

I tried changing stuff in the view model , adapter , main and secondary fragments (which is supposed to display the recycler view). nothing works so maybe the main problem is the data class as i mentioned above.

Comment: could you please add some snippets how you configure `RecyclerView`?

Comment: I uploaded it to github, heres the link https://github.com/giorgishubitidze3/CountryApp 

I made so many changes when I explained the problem to chatgpt i'm not even sure recycler view is set up correctly anymore, but after so many tries thought the problem would be the data class itself.

Comment: The reason is that you create 2 different instances of the `ViewModel`. Thus, you request the data with the first instance, then you create the second instance in `SecondaryFragment`, then the log prints `Received 0 countries` as it returns the `emptyList()` from the `_countryList` declaration. But the result of your request doesn't get to this `_countryList` as it was in the first `ViewModel` instance

Comment: I fixed it and understand now, thanks a lot!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.